# Relating the curvature of a plane curve to the curvature of a stretched version

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

Let $\theta : I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a regular plane curve with curvature $ |k_{\theta}|\leq1$ everywhere.

We now define a curve $\theta_{d}$ by stretching $\theta$ in one direction, i.e.,

$\theta = ( \theta_{1}(t), \theta_{2}(t))$,

$\theta_{d} = (2 \theta_{1}(t), \theta_{2}(t))$

How the curvature of  $\theta_{d} , k_{d} $ relates to $\theta$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard formula for curvature of a plane curve $\alpha(t)$,
$$k = \frac{\|\alpha'(t)\times\alpha''(t)\|}{\|\alpha'(t)\|^3}\,,$$
we find that
$$k_{\theta_d} = \frac{2k_\theta}{(4\theta_1'^2 + \theta_2'^2)^{3/2}}\,.$$
Not so informative, but since the speed of $\theta_d$ is between $1$ and $2$ and you gave the curvature bound on $\theta$, we have
$$\frac{k_\theta}4 \le k_{\theta_d} \le 2{k_\theta}\le 2\,.$$